# Laravel Mongodb Messenger relations data not filtering

Tags: mongodb, laravel-5

I have 3 collection instances with `belongsToMany` relations.

I want to filter data from all 3 collections but not sure how.

Collection Structure.

Payment:

```
{
  "_id": "5ba3c8f7c2ab9b3bed20ae22",
  "code": "GHFH",
  "amount": "345.00"
}
```

User:

```
{
  "_id": "5ba3c87cc2ab9b34be139382",
  "name": "Jack",
  "email": "Pd@gmail.com",
  "payment_ids": [
    "5ba3c8f7c2ab9b3bed20ae22"
  ]
}
```

Customer:

```
{
  "_id": "23c34c87cc2ab9b34b3423423",
  "name": "cfb",
  "email": "Psfsdd@gmail.com",
  "payment_ids": [
    "5ba3c8f7c2ab9b3bed20ae22"
  ]
}
```

I have create below query.

```
$cruds = payment::with([
        'user' => function ($query) {
            $query->orWhere('name','like', "%'".$search."'%");
        }, 
        'customer' => function ($query) {
            $query->orWhere('name','like', "%'".$search."'%");
        }
    ])
    ->orWhere('code','like', "%'".$search."'%")
    ->orWhere('amount', 'like', "%'".$search."'%")
    ->offset($start)
    ->limit($limit)
    ->orderBy($order, $dir)
    ->get();
```

Please Suggest.

I have change in query.

```
 $cruds = payment::with([
                    'user' => function ($query) {
                        $query->where('name','like', "%{$search}%");
                    }, 
                    'customer' => function ($query) {
                        $query->where('name','like', "%{$search}%");
                    }
                ])
            ->where('code','like', "%{$search}%")
            ->where('amount', 'like', "%{$search}%")
            ->offset($start)
            ->limit($limit)
            ->orderBy($order, $dir)
            ->get();
```

Comment: So have you get all collections in variables e.g. `$payment`, `$customers` etc?

Comment: Do we need to get all collection result separately ? Can we do combine result set?

Comment: No you don't was just trying to understand what was happening. On each `with()` closure, why are you using `orWhere()`. It should just be `where()`. Also, I don't think you need to put the single quotes around `$search`.

Comment: Right now i am able to get result with below query. -  $cruds = payment::with('user', 'customer')->where('code', '=', 'SDFSDF')->orderBy('updated_at', 'desc')->get();  but now need to check in User and customer table.

Comment: Is below query file ? any changes need ?
$cruds = payment::with([
                        'user' => function ($query) {
                            $query->where('name','like', "%{$search}%");
                        }, 
                        'customer' => function ($query) {
                            $query->where('name','like', "%{$search}%");
                        }
                    ])
                ->where('code','like', "%{$search}%")
                ->where('amount', 'like', "%{$search}%")
                ->get();

Comment: This should do it, has it worked?

Comment: I have try same, but it is not working.

Comment: What error are you recieving?

Comment: I am getting blank object. see below. <pre>Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection Object
(
    [items:protected] => Array
        (
        )

)

Comment: if i am trying below, it is returning all payment table result. not proper filter.payment::with([
                    'user' => function ($query) {
                        $query->where('name','like', "%Avin%");
                    }, 
                    'customer' => function ($query) {
                        $query->where('name','like', "%Avin%");
                    }
                ])
            ->get();